# Customized email alert to members

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Here's the scenario I'm trying to implement in a SharePoint list -

The SharePoint list I manage has a field which has 3 choices. Based on each of the choice, the alert that this item has been added needs to go to a person.

Choice #1 -> John Doe
Choice #2 -> Jane Doe
Choice #3 -> Jim Doe

And all alerts should all be copied to Mark Doe.

I tried working this out with workflow, but I'm not able to build this logic into. Could you please help?

This is SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In your SharePoint Designer workflow, do the following:

1. Add a condition that checks the value of the dropdown list. You may need to play around with this to determine if the value match should be against​ the text or the index value of the selection.
2. If the value is the first in the list, send the email to John Doe and copy Mark.
3. If the value isn't the first, add a nested step that checks if the value is the second.
4. If it is the second, send email to Jane and copy Mark.
5. If the value isn't the second, add a nested step that checks if the value is the third.
6. If it is the third, send email to Jim and copy Mark.